# Facebook fql query to get links shared by friends not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to run this query from couple of days and it either gets hanged or I get an error saying "An unknown error occured"

```
select title from link where owner in ( select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())
```

Basically I am trying to find all links shared by my friends - not pages that my friends like - I know I can get that information from page_fan table

I'm testing the query here

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/

Any help from you guys will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: have you taken proper permission for that?

Comment: What is the required permission for that - I have the "friends_likes" permission and that gives me access to the pages the friends like - but not the links they share

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding the LIMIT clause to the above query

`select title from link where owner in ( select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())  limit 100`

Hope it helps someone !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to do it with the Graph-API's "links" connection (documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/)).
The Graph-API has pagination built in so maybe it solves your problem (haven't tested)

1. get all your friends  - [https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/friends)
2. for every friend, get all her "links" connections - https://graph.facebook.com/FRIEND_ID/links